# Spring cloud zuul does not load static resources from spring boot applications

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reverse-proxy, netflix-zuul

I have a simple gateway that implemented with zuul as you can see below:

`application.properties` file:

```
zuul.routes.looli.url=http://localhost:8082
ribbon.eureka.enabled=false
server.port=8070
```

`RoutingAndFilteringGatewayApplication` class:

```
@EnableZuulProxy
@SpringBootApplication
public class RoutingAndFilteringGatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RoutingAndFilteringGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleFilter simpleFilter() {
        return new SimpleFilter();
    }

}
```

and the `SimpleFilter` class:

```
public class SimpleFilter extends ZuulFilter {

  private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleFilter.class);

  @Override
  public String filterType() {
    return "pre";
  }

  @Override
  public int filterOrder() {
    return 1;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean shouldFilter() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public Object run() {
    RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();

    log.info(String.format("%s request to %s", request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURL().toString()));

    return null;
  }

}
```

and this is the structure of **looli** application:

```
  src
    |_main
          |_java
          |_resources
          |_webapp
                 |_dist
                 |     |_js
                 |     |_css
                 |     |_img
                 |
                 |_index.html
```

Now, when i enter **localhost:8070/looli** in the browser it loads index.html, but get 404 error for all of static resources under dist directory.

**NOTE**

After i googled my problem, i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52855451/spring-cloud-zuul-proxy-gateway-does-not-load-css-js-from-spring-boot-applicati) question on SO and also checked his solution by creating **looli** folder under **resources**, but didn't affect.

I'm new to zull ;)

Answer (score 0):

Whatch this post: [CSS not loading in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203402/css-not-loading-in-spring-boot), you need put you static content into templates folder